Reading Data Using Modbus RTU Over RS-485
I am working on transmitting temperature data from an E32 module to an E95-DTU. I attempted to send the data in a Modbus RTU structure using the following format:
01 04 02 09 A1 7E D8
However, when I attempt to receive the data, I get the following response:
FB 01 02 09 A1 7E D8
Could you please explain what the "FB" byte signifies? I did not include it in the data I sent. Additionally, I would appreciate guidance on preparing the correct format to ensure successful data transmission.
#include "LoRa_E32.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int16_t temperature; 
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2);  
LoRa_E32 e32(&mySerial);


uint16_t calculateCRC(uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t length) {
  uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    crc ^= buffer[i];
    for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if (crc & 0x0001) {
        crc >>= 1;
        crc ^= 0xA001;
      } else {
        crc >>= 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return crc;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  

  e32.begin();


void loop() {
 
  temperature = 2465; 

  uint8_t modbusPacket[8];
  modbusPacket[0] = 0x01;  
  modbusPacket[1] = 0x04;  
  modbusPacket[2] = 0x02;  


  modbusPacket[3] = (temperature >> 8) & 0xFF;  
  modbusPacket[4] = temperature & 0xFF;         

  // CRC hesapla
  uint16_t crc = calculateCRC(modbusPacket, 5); 
  modbusPacket[5] = crc & 0xFF;                 
  modbusPacket[6] = (crc >> 8) & 0xFF;         


  e32.sendMessage(modbusPacket, sizeof(modbusPacket));

 
  Serial.print("Sent Packet: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(modbusPacket); i++) {
    Serial.print(modbusPacket[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();

  delay(1000);
}


I would like to get my sensor data with modbus rtu protocol. What should I do? Why am I getting crc errors?



Your code just looks like it's sending data over LoRa? I see no mention of RS485, no request handling so it's not really Modbus, and the responses shown in your screenshot don't contain the FB mentioned in your question? (so please edit the title and add detail). I suspect one of your issues is that you define/send an eight byte buffer (uint8_t modbusPacket[8]) but only set seven bytes (i.e. no modbusPacket[7]=...). Try reducing the buffer size (uint8_t modbusPacket[7]).
